# Loop parameters not working inside of function jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, loops

Everything else within the loop works fine until it gets to the .change function. when I remove the (i + 1) and write the id as minMax1 it works fine so it seems to be something to do with the loop variable. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Outside of the function the console returns 4 different values but inside it returns the same one 4 times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var wC = weather[i].conditions;
    var lowC = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i].low.celsius;
    var highC = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i].high.celsius;
    var lowF = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i].low.fahrenheit;
    var highF = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i].high.fahrenheit;
    var fDay = data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[i].date.weekday_short;

    console.log (wC);

    switch (wC) {
        case "Clear": case "Sunny":
            $("#weatherIcon" + (i + 1)).addClass ("wi wi-day-sunny");
            break;
        case "Mostly Sunny": case "Mostly Clear": case "Partly Sunny": case "Partly Cloudy":
            $("#weatherIcon" + (i + 1)).addClass ("wi wi-day-cloudy");
            break;
        case "Mostly Cloudy": case "Overcast": case "Scattered Clouds":
            $("#weatherIcon" + (i + 1)).addClass ("wi wi-cloudy");
            break;
    }

    $("#todayTemp").html (todayTempC + "&deg;");
    $("#minMax" + (i + 1)).html (lowC + "&deg; / " + highC + "&deg;");

    $("input:radio[name=\"system\"]").change (function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "cel"){
        $("#todayTemp").html (todayTempC + "&deg;");
        $("#minMax" + (i + 1)).html (lowC + "&deg; / " + highC + "&deg;");
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "far") {
        $("#todayTemp").html (todayTempF + "&deg;");
        $("#minMax" + (i + 1)).html (lowF + "&deg; / " + highF + "&deg;");
    }
 });

$("#fDay" + i).html (fDay);
```

}

Comment: You are using var i inside the change() function. This value changes in each loop, so `$("input:radio[name=\"system\"]").change`  definition is assigned 4 times with different logic. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: It's supposed to change 4 numbers from celsius to fahrenheit.

Comment: The numbers are inside id's called minMax1, minMax2 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the callback method, *i* refers to the value of *i* when the callback is called. This means that *i* will always be 4 at that time (the callback will always execute after the loop has finished all iterations). You'll need to create a separate context for each iteration to access the value at the current iteration.

Array.forEach will do this automatically for example.

```
['a', 'b'].forEach(function (value, i) {
    //First iteration: value = 'a', i = 0 
    //Second iteration: value = 'b', i = 1
});
```

You can also bind *i* to your callback method. See this example:

http://jsbin.com/xuhoduhuxi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Cheers :) how would I apply that forEach to my code?

Comment: Something like this should work:
http://jsbin.com/voqofoyidi/10/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: That works brilliant thankyou :) i'm pulling the everything from an API, how else could I work that around the weathers array?

Comment: I think this has sorted it, changed "partly clear" etc.. to weather[0].conditions etc... thankyou :D